iwlwifi: probe of 0000:05:00.0 failed with error -110
I have a dual-booted PC (Ubuntu 23.10 + Windows). I recently upgraded the Win 10 partition to Win 11. WiFi on my Ubuntu install stopped working, with the following dmesg logs:
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: CSR_RESET = 0x10
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x0
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0x3f7f8830
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 1]: 0x3f7f8430
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 2]: 0x3f7f0c30
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 3]: 0x3f7f0030
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 4]: 0x3f7f8c30
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 5]: 0x3f7f8830
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 6]: 0x3f7f0430
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 7]: 0x3f7f8430
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 8]: 0x3f7f8830
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 9]: 0x3f7f8430
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 10]: 0x3f7f8830
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 11]: 0x3f7f0030
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 12]: 0x3f7f0c30
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 13]: 0x3f7f0030
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 14]: 0x3f7f8c30
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x1
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0x044466c2
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 1]: 0x044466c2
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 2]: 0x044466c2
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 3]: 0x044466c2
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 4]: 0x044466c2
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 5]: 0x044466c2
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 6]: 0x044466c2
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 7]: 0x044466c2
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 8]: 0x044466c2
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 9]: 0x044466c2
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 10]: 0x044466c2
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 11]: 0x044466c2
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 12]: 0x044466c2
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 13]: 0x044466c2
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 14]: 0x044466c2
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x6
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0xa00c4471
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 1]: 0xf00c4471
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 2]: 0xf00c4471
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 3]: 0xa00c4471
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 4]: 0xb00c4471
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 5]: 0xe00c4471
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 6]: 0xe00c4471
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 7]: 0xb00c4471
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 8]: 0xa00c4471
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 9]: 0xe00c4471
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 10]: 0xf00c4471
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 11]: 0xe00c4471
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 12]: 0xf00c4471
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 13]: 0xf00c4471
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 14]: 0xf00c4471
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Host monitor block 0x22 vector 0x0
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0x00000000
May 18 12:46:56 arctic kernel: iwlwifi: probe of 0000:05:00.0 failed with error -110

When I go into the Ubuntu settings, I don't see any options for WiFi -- it's like my system doesn't think it has a Wifi card at all.
$ uname -a
Linux arctic 6.5.0-27-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Mar  7 18:21:00 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


I resolved this by booting into Win11 and disabling fast startup.
However, I have absolutely no idea why this worked -- how do Win 11 boot settings interfere with Ubuntu boot settings?
